# Left side border is not displaying on menubar

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I have created CSS menu bar for my webpage. But Left side border is not displaying when some one move mouse on "My Presentations" link. Currently "My Favorite" link is selected. Please notice Left side gray border is not displaying on "My Favorite" link. But when u move mouse on "Friend's Favorite" link then right side border in displaying on "My Favorite" link. I need to display left side border to.

Here is the link:- 
[jsFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/gauravishere/fAA5T/2/)

```
 <ul class="menu" style="margin-top:20px;">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="my-presentations.htm">My Presentations</a></li>
    <li class="current"><a href="myFavorite.htm">My Favorite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Friend's Favorite</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Most Viewed</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Sync account</a></li>
</ul>

  /* NAVBAR CSS START HERE */     
.menu,.menu ul,.menu li,.menu a {margin: 0;padding: 0;border: none;outline: none;}
.menu {height: 30px;width: 759px;background: #3B5998;border:1px solid #e1e1e1; border-top-left-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topright:5px}
.menu li {position: relative;list-style: none;float: left;display: block;height: 30px;}
.menu ul { display: none;}
.menu li a{display: block;padding: 0 14px;line-height: 30px;text-decoration: none;font-family: Tahoma;font-weight: bold;font-size: 11px;color: #f9f9f9;border-left:1px solid #8698C0;}
.menu li:hover > a{ color: #9a9a9a; background:#fff; border-left:1px solid #ccc;}
.menu li a.first{border-left:0px; background:#ffvv00;}
.menu li.current a{border:0px; height:31px;color: #9a9a9a; background:#fff; margin-top:-3px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:4px;border-top-left-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; border-top-right-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topright:5px;} 
.menu li:first-child a:hover{border-top-left-radius:5px;-moz-border-radius-topleft:5px; border-right:1px #ccc solid; margin-right:-1px;}
.menu li:last-child a{border-right: none; }
```

Comment: hey height of current menu item is kinda big compared to others. Do you need it that way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did many changes to the code, it better to take look at the demo

[New Demo](http://jsbin.com/ofewug/7/edit)

***Note :*** 
*I am not sure, why you made your active element more taller than other elements, and they have some rounded edge. It looks odd*

Comment: Thanks for reply...But its Not the correct one. Have u seen left side Border on First Link. And i need current selected link little up. That's why i have given -3 top margin. I think you have deleted -3 top margin...But i need to show selected link little big then other links...

Comment: check the demo now, changed it a bit

Comment: Wow.. Thanks Syed.. It works now...Thanks for the help Syed... I will show you the sample some time when my page will be completed... then tell me its looking good or not..:) Thanks ...